# Logging each process to a different log file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am rather new in Python, and logging multiprocesses seems confusing to me. Currently using Python 3.6.6

I created a script to setup my handlers and to allow me to create unique log names (which I want for each process) or use a main log file.

In console I want to display warnings and errors, in the log file I want to track debug messages.

**logging_config.py**

```
import logging
import sys
import os
import pathlib

CONSOLE_FORMATER = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s - %(message)s")
FILE_FORMATTER = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d - %(message)s'")


def getConsoleHandler():
    consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    consoleHandler.setFormatter(CONSOLE_FORMATER)
    consoleHandler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    return consoleHandler


def getFileHandler(**kwargs):
    path = createLogDir()

    if 'logName' in kwargs:
        logFile = path + "/" + kwargs['logName'] + ".log"
    else:
        logFile = path + "/deploy-orchestrator.log"

    # fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(logFile, mode='w')
    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(logFile)
    fileHandler.setFormatter(FILE_FORMATTER)
    fileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return fileHandler


def createLogDir():
    path = f"{os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())}/logs"   # get working parent dir
    pathlib.Path(path).mkdir(exist_ok=True)  # create /logs dir, if it exists throw no errors
    return path


# if uniqueLog is set to true then a log will be made with the logger name
def getLogger(loggerName, **kwargs):
    logger = logging.getLogger(loggerName)
    logger.addHandler(getConsoleHandler())

    if 'uniqueLog' in kwargs and kwargs['uniqueLog'] is True:
        logger.addHandler(getFileHandler(logName=loggerName))
    else:
        logger.addHandler(getFileHandler())

    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.propagate = False
    return logger
```

For simple logging I can just import my logging_config and log anything I need.

**simple_example.py**

```
import logging_config as logs

logger = logs.getLogger(__name__)

logger.debug("This works just fine and goes into the default log file")
logger.warning("This works just fine and goes to console and the log file")
```

Now for what is not working.

**multiprocess_parent.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Process

processes = []
for child_name in children:
    process_child = ProcessChild(child_name)
    p = Process(target=process_child.worker, args=(widget))

    processes.append(p)
    p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

**multiprocess_child.py**

```
import logging_config as logs

class ProcessChild:
    logger = None

    def __init__(self, child_name):
        self.child_name = child_name
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(child_name, uniqueLog=True)  # Each child getting it's own log file

    def worker(widget):
        logger.info("This EXPLODES")
```

The error I get is `ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects`

And it comes from this line `p.start()`

So how do you write in separate log files for each process in this situation? Is it my initial idea of creating a `logging_config.py` at fault here? I did that so that multiple modules can use the same configuration.

On another note the log files themselves get created properly with the right name, it's when each process tries to write to the proper log file that this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to coding in Python as well. I could be off but it looks like in your multiprocess_child.py when you define your *worker* method, *logger* is not being correctly called.

For example if you want to use the global variable *logger* under your *ProcessChild* class in a defined method, you would use *ProcessChild.logger* (see below).

```
logger = None

def __init__(self, child_name):
    self.child_name = child_name
    ProcessChild.logger = logging.getLogger(child_name, uniqueLog=True)

def worker(widget):
    ProcessChild.logger.info("This EXPLODES")
```